# Finding a 90 degree angle in robodk path and creating two 90 degree vectors at found point

Tags: python, geometry, point

I have a xyzijk list of points and I want to search the list for points that have angle of 90 degrees to next and previous point using a point as a corner.

[image: Visual aid for my explanation]

How can I find P1 from that list and create two points that have 90 degree vectors as shown in the image?

```
125.15790, 50.00000, 139.30003  ,  0.00028, -0.02356, -0.99972,
89.54415, 50.00000, 103.68629  ,  0.70711, 0.00000, -0.70711
139.30003, 50.00000, 125.15790  ,  -0.99972, -0.02356, 0.00028,
125.15790, 50.00000, 139.30003  ,  0.00028, -0.02356, -0.99972
103.68629, 50.00000, 89.54415  ,  -0.70711, 0.00000, 0.70711,
139.30003, 50.00000, 125.15790  ,  -0.99972, -0.02356, 0.00028
```

I've tried calculating the dot product of different points but I'm not sure if that is the proper way to approach this or I've just used it wrong.

Comment: You just have a list of values. A point is specified by 2 values x,y. where is x and y?

Comment: @Onyambu, or is it x, y, z?

Comment: @lit its possible. Though OP has to specify so. a point as long as is in a plane/or in any space of greater than 1d must have more than 1d values to uniquely identify it. Here OP has a plane. so must have >1value